# How do I bring the button forward?

Tags: swift

I put buttons on the storyboard and placed them where the blocks would fall, but the block is blocking/covering the button. How do I bring the button forward?

```
import UIKit

class interestViewController: UIViewController {

var squareView: UIView!
var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    squareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))

    view.addSubview(squareView)
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)

    squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
    collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [squareView])
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    animator.addBehavior(collision)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Use UIView's bringSubviewToFront.

Comment: I did this and I'm getting an error                                                        @IBAction func sports(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.sports)
    }